# how to get the summation of column in the last row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-management

```
select csm.csmCustomerName, cur.curNameOfCurrency, 
sum(sot.sotItemTotalAmount)as 'TotalItemsAmount',
SUM(sorTotalTaxAmountValue) as 'TotalTax',
SUM(sorTotalChargeDetailsAmountValue) as 'TotalCharges',
(sum(sorTotalTaxAmountValue)+sum(sorTotalChargeDetailsAmountValue)+sum(sot.sotItemTotalAmount)) as 'NetAmount'
from dbo.SalesOrder sor join dbo.Currency cur
on sor.sorCurrencyId=cur.curId
join dbo.CustomerMaster csm
on sor.sorCustomerMasterId=csm.csmId
join SalesOrderItemDetails sot
on sot.sotSalesOrderId=sor.sorId
Group by csmCustomerName, curNameOfCurrency with rollup;
```

I want the sum of `TotalItemsAmount`, `TotalTax`, `TotalCharges` and `NetAmount` in the last row of respective columns.
In result set, I get duplication of each row, could anyone correct the mistake in my code.

---

C1  C2   C3  C4 C5  C6

A   USD 1   7   2   10

B   USD 3   6   3   12

C   USD 5   3   0   8

D   USD 4   2   1   7

```
   13  18   6  37
```

Comment: Could you share some data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Without appropriate same data and expected output, it is hard to answer . Are you looking for something like `WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: To get summation of the column in its last row, I used GROUP BY and ROLL UP clause (shown in code), but duplication of each rows generated with NULL when I execute. I want to avoid the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done via the grouping sets like:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( code CHAR(3), a INT, b INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'USD', 1, 2 ),
        ( 'USD', 5, 1 ),
        ( 'USD', 10, 7 ),
        ( 'EUR', 15, 13 )


SELECT  code ,
        SUM(a) AS a ,
        SUM(b) AS b
FROM    @t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(( code ), ( ))
```

Output:

```
code    a   b
EUR     15  13
USD     16  10
NULL    31  23
```